# Can you have multiple Keys in SQL and why would you want that?

Tags: mysql, sql, key

Is there a reason why you would want to have multiple KEYs in a TABLE? What is the point of having multiple KEYs in one table?

Here is an example that I found:

```
CREATE TABLE orders(
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT,
user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
transaction_id VARCHAR(19) NOT NULL,
payment_status VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
payment_amount DECIMAL(15) NOT NULL,
payment_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY(id),
KEY(user_id),
)
```

Also, you'll notice the DBase programmer doesn't make `transaction_id` a `KEY`. Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`KEY` in MySQL is an alternate syntax for "index".
Indexes are common across databases, but they aren't covered by ANSI as of yet -- it's pure miracle things are as similar as they are.  It can be common to have more than one index associated to a table -- because indexes improve data retrieval at the cost of update/delete/insert speed.

Be aware that MySQL (5.x?) automatically creates an index if one doesn't already exist for the primary key of a table.

Comment: The SQL Standards define a language that is relationally complete as regards Codd's rules (including some of the things he got wrong :) _By definition_ it avoids making assumptions about the underlying storage including indexes.

Answer (score 4):

There are several possible reasons.

- Enhance search performance (when the WHERE clause uses KEY fields, it performs faster)
- Restrain table contents (when using a UNIQUE key for a column, it can't have the same value twice or more on it)

These are the most common reasons.

Comment: In this case, why wouldn't I make everything a key then? That way I can search everything quicker?

Comment: updating many indexes is expensive. This would slow down your updates and inserts.

Comment: @Rasika So you're saying that if I make a column a KEY I would have to make sure to update all other KEYs that relate to this same KEY in this particular TABLE? Is that why it's expensive?

Comment: No, The updates to the keys will happen automatically by the DB server. However, as it has to do more updates that will load up the server. This is why you have a disable keys option to speed up inserts when you are doing bulk inserts. Each time an insert is done, the server goes and updates all relevant indexes in that table. Not necessarily on the related tables.

Comment: @Rasika is there a place I can learn about how this updates the KEYs automatically?

Comment: How MySQL uses Indexes would be a good starting point: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

Answer (score 3):

In SQL you may only have one `PRIMARY KEY` per table.

`KEY(foo)` is bogus syntax in standard SQL. In MySQL `KEY foo` is a poorly named synonym for `INDEX foo` and does not impose a UNIQUE constraint. (It is poorly named because it does not actually relate to the functioning of a key.)

There may be multiple `UNIQUE INDICES` which can play the role of "candidate keys". (A unique constraint can be specified without an associated INDEX, but the point of a "key" is generally a *quick look-up*.) The point of a `PRIMARY KEY` is to *uniquely identify a single record* and is almost exclusively INDEX-backed and may even be directly related to the clustering of the data.

Only the minimal amount of [unique] INDICES required to *ensure data validity* and *meet performance requirements* should be used -- they impose performance penalties on the query engine as well as have additional update and maintenance costs.

*Non-unique* INDEX's (`INDEX foo`, or in the case of MySQL, `KEY foo`) are purely to allow the database to optimize queries. They do not *really* map to "keys" and may be referred to as "covering indices"; if selected by the query planner these indices can aid in performance even though they add nothing to the logical model itself. (For performance reasons, a database engine may require that FOREIGN KEYS are covered by indices.)

In this case, creating an INDEX (*don't think "KEY"!*) on `user_id` will generally (greatly) speed up queries with clauses like:

```
... WHERE user_id = {somenumber}
```

Without the INDEX the above query would require a FULL TABLE SCAN (e.g. read through all records).

While I do not know why `transaction_id` is not made an index, it might not be required (or even detrimental for the given *access patterns*) -- consider the case where *every* query that needs to be fast either:

1. Does not use `transaction_id` or;
2. Also has a `user_id = ...` or other restriction that can utilize an INDEX. That is, in a case like `WHERE user_id = ... AND transaction_id = ...` the query planner will *likely* first find the records *for the matched user* and then look for the matching `transaction_id` -- it still has to do a SCAN, but only over a *much smaller data-set* than the original table. Only a plain `WHERE transaction_id = ...` would necessarily require a FULL TABLE SCAN.

If in doubt, use [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) -- or other [query analyzer](http://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/query.html) -- and see what MySQL *thinks* it should do. As a last note, sometimes estimated query execution plans may differ from actual execution plans and *outdated statistics* can make the query planner choose a non-ideal plan.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

"Keys" might refer to one of:

- [Index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/column-indexes.html) (search optimization)
- Constraint (e.g. [foreign key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html), [primary key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/constraint-primary-key.html))

You may want multiple because you need to implement more than one of these features in a single table.  It's actually quite common.

Answer (score 0):

In database theory, a key is a constraint that enforces uniqueness. A relvar (analogous to a SQL table) may indeed have more than one candidate key. A classic example is the set of chemical elements, for which name, symbol, atomic number and atomic weight are all keys (and folk will still want to add their own surrogate key to it ;)

MySQL continues a long tradition of abuse of the word `KEY` by making it a synonym for `INDEX`. Clearly, a MySQL table may have as many indexes as deemed necessary for performance for a given set of circumstances.

From your SQL DDL, it seems clear the ID is a surrogate key, so we must look for a natural key with not much to go on. While `transaction_id` may be a candidate, it is not inconceivable that an order can involve more than one transaction. In practical terms, I think an auditor would be suspicious of multiple orders made by the same user simultaneously, therefore suggest the compound of `user_id` and `payment_time` should be a key. However, if `transaction_id` is not a key then the table would not be fully normalized. Therefore, I'd give the designer the benefit of the doubt and assume `transaction_id` is also a key.